# How to find interfaces with specified annotation using ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider?

Tags: spring, reflection

I try to replace org.reflections:reflections library by org.springframework:spring-context and `ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider`  because reflections library has a bug that is critical for me.
I want to find all classes, interfaces and subclasses that contain specific annotation. It was easy in reflections:

```
var subTypeScanner = new SubTypesScanner( true );
        var typeAnnotationScanner = new TypeAnnotationsScanner();
        var configBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder().setUrls( ClasspathHelper.forPackage( "com.example" ) )
                .setScanners( subTypeScanner, typeAnnotationScanner );

        Reflections reflections= new Reflections( configBuilder );
        Set<Class<?>> typesAnnotatedWith = reflections.getTypesAnnotatedWith(Path.class);
```

Unfortunately it is not easy for me using `ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider`. I have made workaround to  find subclasses. First I find set of classes and after that I search for subclasses separately for each class:

```
protected Set< Class< ? > > findClasses( ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider aScanner )
    {
        return aScanner.findCandidateComponents( "com.example" )
            .stream()
            .map( BeanDefinition::getBeanClassName )
            .map( e -> {
                try
                {
                    return Class.forName( e );
                }
                catch( ClassNotFoundException aE )
                {
                    throw new RuntimeException( aE );
                }
            } )
            .collect( Collectors.toUnmodifiableSet() );
    }


protected Set< Class< ? > > findSubClasses( Set< Class< ? > > aClasses )
    {
        return aClasses.stream()
                .map( aClass -> {
                    ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider scanner =
                            new ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider( false );
                    scanner.addIncludeFilter( new AssignableTypeFilter( aClass ) );
                    return scanner.findCandidateComponents( "com.example" );

                } )
                .flatMap(Collection::stream)
                .map( BeanDefinition::getBeanClassName )
                .map( e -> {
                    try
                    {
                        return Class.forName( e );
                    }
                    catch( ClassNotFoundException aE )
                    {
                        throw new RuntimeException( aE );
                    }
                } )
                .collect( Collectors.toUnmodifiableSet() );
    }
```

Unfortunately I do not know how to find interfaces with annotation. Following code does not finds interfaces. It only finds classes that has `Path` annotation or extends class or implements interface that has `Path` annotation.

```
ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider scanner =
            new ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider( false );
    scanner.addIncludeFilter( new AnnotationTypeFilter( Path.class, true, true ) );
    Set<Class<?>> classes = findClasses(scanner);
    //findSubClasses(findClasses( scanner ))
```

How to find interfaces with `Path` annotation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The current implementation is also clear as mentioned on method level docs

> The default implementation checks whether the class is not an interface and not dependent on an enclosing class.

As per this github [issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/17399) we can fix this by overridden behaviour of `isCandidateComponent()` method

Here is the sample reference working code from the github issue

```java
  provider = new ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider(false) {
            @Override
            protected boolean isCandidateComponent(AnnotatedBeanDefinition beanDefinition) {
                return super.isCandidateComponent(beanDefinition) || beanDefinition.getMetadata().isAbstract();
            }
        };
```

Annotation

```java
package in.silentsudo.classpathannotationscanner.annotation;

import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Retention(value = RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
public @interface MyCustomAnnotation {
}
```

My Simple interface

```java
package in.silentsudo.classpathannotationscanner;

import in.silentsudo.classpathannotationscanner.annotation.MyCustomAnnotation;

@MyCustomAnnotation
public interface SimpleInterface {
}
```

Sample test code

```java
package in.silentsudo.classpathannotationscanner;

import in.silentsudo.classpathannotationscanner.annotation.MyCustomAnnotation;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AnnotatedBeanDefinition;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanDefinition;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider;
import org.springframework.core.type.filter.AnnotationTypeFilter;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/list")
public class SampleController {

    private final ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider provider;

    SampleController() {
        provider = new ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider(false) {
            @Override
            protected boolean isCandidateComponent(AnnotatedBeanDefinition beanDefinition) {
                return super.isCandidateComponent(beanDefinition) || beanDefinition.getMetadata().isAbstract();
            }
        };
        provider.addIncludeFilter(new AnnotationTypeFilter(MyCustomAnnotation.class, true, true));
    }

    @GetMapping
    public Map<String, Object> list() throws Exception {
        return Map.of("mycustomannotationsmarkedinterafce", getData());
    }

    public List<String> getData() throws Exception {
        final Set<BeanDefinition> classes = provider.findCandidateComponents("in.silentsudo.classpathannotationscanner");
        List<String> names = new ArrayList<>();
        for (BeanDefinition bean : classes) {
            Class<?> clazz = Class.forName(bean.getBeanClassName());
            names.add(clazz.getName());
        }
        return names;
    }
}
```

This should give following response:

```json
{
"mycustomannotationsmarkedinterafce": [
"in.silentsudo.classpathannotationscanner.SimpleInterface"
]
}
```